# How to improve my Rest Calls on Android?

Tags: android, xml, json, rest, google-play

I am making an app for Android. I like to make the rest calls as quick as possible. When I get my results as XML it takes 5 seconds (!) to get a simple xml like this:

```
   <souvenirs>
     <souvenir>
       <id>1</id>
       <name>Example 1</name>
       <rating>3.4</rating>
       <photourl>/images/example.jpg</photourl>
       <price>3.50</price>
     </souvenir>
     <souvenir>
       <id>2</id>
       <name>Example 2</name>
       <rating>2.4</rating>
       <photourl>/images/example.jpg</photourl>
       <price>8.50</price>
       </souvenir>
   </souvenirs>
```

So I tried it with JSON. But that takes also about 5 seconds to retrieve.

I load the XML in android with the following code:

```
        URL url = new URL("http://example.nu?method=getAllSouvenirs");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            long t=System.currentTimeMillis();

            InputStream ins = conn.getInputStream();
            Log.d("info", String.valueOf((System.currentTimeMillis()-t)));
```

The log says it takes about 5000 ms to get the inputstream.. Is there any way to speed this up? does anybody knows which technique the Android Market uses? This loads way faster than my app..

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You sure that the server isn't the problem because it's too slow?

Answer (score 2):

When you try to get the data "manually" - via browser or via other means (wget, curl) how long does it take there.

On Android you also should take the mobile network into consideration that is usually significantly slower than for a desktop computer. Also latencies are bigger.

To me this sounds a lot like issues in the backend (e.g. trying to resolve the IP of the client and thus taking lots of time).

Answer (score 1):

use Apache HttpClient instead of URLConnection:
[Apache http client or URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799151/apache-http-client-or-urlconnection)

EDIT(2012-02-07): no longer true on newer android platform please read: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: No matter if you use HttpClient or UrlConnection or carrier pigeons that should not take 5sec with a decent remote.

Comment: @Heiko Rupp true ... but HttpClient seems to be quicker then UrlConnection

Comment: So, I tried HttpClient now. results:

      04-20 14:00:47.011: DEBUG/info(7126): json call duration: 3312

      04-20 14:01:26.621: DEBUG/info(7126): json call duration: 3207
      04-20 14:01:27.631: DEBUG/info(7126): json call duration: 1009
      04-20 14:01:42.521: DEBUG/info(7126): json call duration: 2103
      04-20 14:01:43.861: DEBUG/info(7126): json call duration: 1333
      04-20 14:02:00.651: DEBUG/info(7126): json call duration: 5148
      04-20 14:02:01.841: DEBUG/info(7126): json call duration: 1190

Comment: @Martijn538 so now call takes aprox 2 sec. ?

Comment: When I open my activity and I restart it immediately (by pressing back and forth in the menu it's around 2 seconds.. But when I wait for half a minute it's around the 3/4 seconds..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is how it is implemented and you can't do nothing. That is my guess.
My opinion is to do all connection based stuff on your own thread (to put in in background) and in foreground (main UI thread) entertain user. :)

I have played a little bit around this and it works fast enough for me... Here is my code:

```
private static HttpResponse doPost(String url, JSONStringer json) {
    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity entity;
        entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());

        entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
        request.setEntity(entity);

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            return response;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And somewhere else I call that method like:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = doPost(url, json);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
```

It works fine for me...

Comment: Thanks, when I execute the url on my computer, it only takes about 100ms, so that isn't the problem. I'm just wondering how it's possible to make my app as fast as the Android Market..

Comment: @Martijn try this from the browser on your mobile.

Comment: I tried and this is faster than using it in my app. 

Right now I'm trying to implement Keepalive to my httpClient. Does anybody know how to do this? I heard that reusing the HttpClient in the App improves the speed. I reused my HttpClient by creating it in the Main Activity. Then, when starting another Activity, I passed it to my Intent (putExtra) and made my HttpClient Parceable.. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Based on the process I describe above, it takes me 307 milliseconds to call `doPost` method and 2 milliseconds for `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));` I have tried this on emulator. If I set speed and latency of emulator to GPRS numbers are 628 and 3 milliseconds respectfully.

Comment: It occurs to me that only the first call is taking long. Now I implemented my own restclient AND the method of  ZMeda. I get the following results:

call duration: 2401
json call duration: 416
call duration: 1485
json call duration: 908
call duration: 1142
json call duration: 864
call duration: 1229
json call duration: 635
call duration: 1459
json call duration: 575

Isn't there any way I can speed this more up? if you guys want to try the url : 

http://91.121.69.135/~jpmwebd/android/?method=getAllSouvenirs

Comment: When I test it via the emulator on GPRS: 

04-20 14:10:09.146: DEBUG/info(518): call duration : 2790
04-20 14:10:28.196: DEBUG/info(518): call duration : 902
04-20 14:10:48.467: DEBUG/info(518): call duration : 1767

Comment: So I think I found the problem: When I put my code in an AsyncTask, it takes 2500ms, but when I put my code simply in the oncreate method, it takes 400ms! Don't know how this is possible, but i won't use an asynctask for it anymore..