# How to send a HTTP request in Delphi XE for Android?

Tags: android, delphi, httprequest, delphi-xe5, urlconnection

How to send a HTTP request in Delphi XE5 for Android **without** using `idHTTP` (Indy)?
Quick search revealed that there is no `URLConnection` or usable `AndroidHttpClient` class in Delphi's JNI.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to start a flame war, but why woudl you use delphi XE5? Why not android studio? Are you using the SDK? Because there is a lot of http stuff in the SDK: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html

Comment: @cbrulak, it does not concern my preferences. I love studio, and I watch in awe as it evolves. But at this moment I am working in Delphi, and despite its drawbacks I'll keep working in it because I hope to make it a bit better for mobile development.

Comment: If Delphi does not already provide a JNI wrapper for [`AndroidHttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html), you can easily write your own. Android classes are fairly easy to access via Delphi's JNI framework, and there are third-party import tools starting to pop up to generate Delphi JNI wrappers for Android classes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you should put that is an answer.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551058/ - "According to the android team you should be using HttpURLConnection on Gingerbread and better" (instead of HttpClient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Delphi does not already provide a JNI wrapper for
[AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html),  you can easily
write your own. Android classes are fairly easy to
access via Delphi's JNI framework, there are blogs showing how to do that, and there are
third-party import tools starting to pop up that
generate Delphi JNI wrappers for Android classes.

Comment: It is answer to the more general question than the one that is presented above: 'how to use an Android class that is not present in Delphi XE5?' Nevertheless I'll accept your answer, because it was very usefull.

Comment: For example: [Android2DelphiImport](http://journeyman.ath.cx/Android2DelphiImport.aspx)