# How to change timeout for a request in okhttp

Tags: okhttp

In general we set timeout for the okHttp client and we use single instance of that client. So, we can't change the timeout for that client once it's generated.

**How to change the timeout for a particular request ?? Is there anyway
to do it without creating new client??**

It's very common that some calls take more time atleast 1/2 per app, which needs more timeout than others. it would be great if request can override the default timeout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 3.9 it is possible to set this per request in an interceptor

```java
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/36bd68aa3e93affb12504cd40454e64c6812019c/okhttp-tests/src/test/java/okhttp3/InterceptorTest.java#L747-L757

      @Test public void chainWithReadTimeout() throws Exception {
        Interceptor interceptor1 = new Interceptor() {
          @Override public Response intercept(Chain chainA) throws IOException {
            assertEquals(5000, chainA.readTimeoutMillis());
    
            Chain chainB = chainA.withReadTimeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            assertEquals(100, chainB.readTimeoutMillis());
    
            return chainB.proceed(chainA.request());
          }
        };
      }
```

Comment: Can you please explain this request interceptor? I am using `OKhttp` request but it returns *Timeout* exception after few seconds. How can I set timeout for longer time so it can get response from server.

Comment: Can you please explain this request interceptor? I am using OKhttp request but it returns Timeout exception after few seconds. How can I set timeout for longer time so it can get response from server, or am I doing something wrong? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443134/okhttp-api-request-returns-exception-timeout

Comment: SMH. I have no idea why `Request.Builder().timeout(500)` isn't supported.  Instead, good luck noticing the interceptor buried in DI when looking at the code for this request.

Answer (score 28):

Updating to Retrofit 2.5.0 you can use `Invocation` class

> New: Invocation class provides a reference to the invoked method and argument list as a tag on the underlying OkHttp Call. This can be accessed from an OkHttp interceptor for things like logging, analytics, or metrics aggregation.

In that way, you can create a `SpecificTimeout` annotation to be used only on the requests you need to set a different timeout duration and read its values on an `OkHttp Interceptor` to change the timeout at that point.

Custom Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface SpecificTimeout {
    int duration();
    TimeUnit unit();
}
```

Service Interface

```
public interface GitHubService {
    @GET("/users")
    @SpecificTimeout(duration = 5000, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    Call<List<User>> listUsers();

    @GET("/repos")
    @SpecificTimeout(duration = 15000, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    Call<List<Repo>> listRepos();
}
```

Interceptor

```
class TimeoutInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        final Invocation tag = request.tag(Invocation.class);
        final Method method = tag != null ? tag.method() : null;
        final SpecificTimeout timeout = method != null ? method.getAnnotation(SpecificTimeout.class) : null;

        if (timeout != null) {
           return chain.withReadTimeout(timeout.duration(), timeout.unit())
                       .withConnectTimeout(timeout.duration(), timeout.unit())
                       .withWriteTimeout(timeout.duration(), timeout.unit())
                       .proceed(request);
        }

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

OkHttp Builder

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                //default timeout for not annotated requests
                .readTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(new TimeoutInterceptor())
                .build();
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks!

Comment: I could not make this work since I got an error with RetentionPolicy and ElementType on SpecificTimeout's annotations.

Comment: To make it work in the current Kotlin version, I had to change `@Retention` and `@Target` annotations to: `@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)` and `@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)`.

Answer (score 16):

See https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PerCallSettings.java which creates shallow clones that only modify some settings.

```java
    // Copy to customize OkHttp for this request.
    OkHttpClient client2 = client.newBuilder()
        .readTimeout(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way is to read a custom header on an interceptor and change the current timeout to calls that contains this specific header, it's works better than create a annotation and use reflection to read it. E.G:

```kotlin
class TimeoutInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()

        return request.header("Custom-Timeout")?.let {
            val newTimeout = it.toInt()
            chain.withReadTimeout(newTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .withConnectTimeout(newTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .withWriteTimeout(newTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .proceed(request)
        } ?: chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: Headers would be sent in the request. +1 Annotation

Comment: You can remove reader after setting timeouts in the same interceptor.