# android difference between httpclient and httpurlconnection, which one to implement?

Tags: android

I am always confused that which is to use between httpclient and httpurlconnection,which  one is better httpclient or httpurlconnection? please give yours opinion that it will be clear to me!!

Comment: Please read this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799151/apache-http-client-or-urlconnection