# new to android - what technology should be used to access web service?

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, amazon-web-services

there seems to be many ways to access a REST web service. but different documentation out there states they all have problems and now i am confused what to use.
Here are our options:

**HTTPClient**  - from apache, but deprecated. However Apache does provide some alternative

**HttpURLConnection** - has bugs in it.

**AndroidHttpClient** - includes the workaround for a major bug in HttpURLConnection

I really don’t know which one to use from the list above. Is there one which I am missing that I should be using
to access a REST web service ?

Comment: They all pretty much do the same thing. I use HTTPClient because Apache is the bees knees.

Comment: BUT httpclient has been deprecated. .. why would you still use it ? and what do u mean by bees knees?

Comment: Take a look at what these people have to say. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799151/apache-http-client-or-urlconnection pretty much sums it up. If you ever have a choice to go Apache code or another library, take a good look into Apache before you choose. Apache code its usually excellently well written. As for the bees knees http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bees%20Knees

Comment: @ns47731: Note that the question and accepted answer that you cite are over three years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, to access a REST Web service, you use a higher-level library, like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), that handles more of the work for you.

Otherwise, Google's official recommendation is to use `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: do you see any problems with AndroidHttpClient ?

Comment: @user3134565: It is not Google's official recommendation, as `AndroidHttpClient` is merely a slightly configured `HttpClient` implementation, and Google does not recommend `HttpClient` anymore.

Comment: im not sure that HTTPurlconnection is the answer, please read this: AndroidHttpClient automatically includes the workaround for a major bug in HttpURLConnection in earlier versions of Android as discussed in the Android Developers blog post above. source: https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/06/

Comment: @user3134565: Please read [Google's statement](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html): "For Gingerbread and better, HttpURLConnection is the best choice. New applications should use HttpURLConnection; it is where we will be spending our energy going forward."

Comment: @user3134565: Also, we are referring to two different implementations of a class named `AndroidHttpClient`. I though you were referring to one from the Android SDK. The blogger you cited created a *different* class *also* named `AndroidHttpClient`. I have never used that blogger's implementation and so cannot comment on it.

Comment: ops didn't read carefully

Comment: @user3134565: I nearly missed it myself. Ideally, the blogger would have a chosen a more distinctive name, particularly since the frameworks' own `AndroidHttpClient` should have existed at the time he was writing his library.