# how to form URL to make HTTP request in android?

Tags: java, android, http, httprequest, android-json

I want to make a HTTP request to the url below.

```
http://192.168.1.60/api/check/merge?nodeid=2&tickets=2-0011,2-0010&saleId=140708120131003102,140708115753005302&firsttableid=1&layoutid=1&userid=1
```

I stored the tickets details and sales id details in the string array.

```
String tickets has {2-0011,2-0010} and String saleid has {140708120131003102, 140708115753005302}
```

How to form the URL like this by using that string array?

```
String mergeurl1 = "http://192.168.1.60/api/check/merge?nodeid=2&tickets=";
                try
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<tablenameurl.length;i++)
                    {
                        //System.out.println(ticketidurl[i]+"**"+salesidurl[i]);
                        if(tablenameurl.length==i && tablenameurl != null)
                        {
                            mergeurl1=mergeurl1+ticketidurl[i]+"&";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mergeurl1=mergeurl1+ticketidurl[i]+",";
                        }
                    }
                    mergeurl1=mergeurl1+"saleId=";
                    for(int i=0;i<tablenameurl.length;i++)
                    {
                        //System.out.println(ticketidurl[i]+"**"+salesidurl[i]);
                        if(tablenameurl.length==i)
                        {
                            mergeurl1=mergeurl1+salesidurl[i]+"&";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mergeurl1=mergeurl1+salesidurl[i]+",";
                        }
                    }
                    mergeurl1=mergeurl1+"&firsttableid=1&layoutid=1&userid=1";
                    System.out.println("URL");
                    System.out.println(mergeurl1);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
```

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: check now @Scary Wombat..

Comment: instead of string use stringBuffer and append the remaining parameters in loop...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330392/on-android-make-a-post-request-with-url-encoded-form-data-without-using-urlenco       this ll help u

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a URL Encoder for this purpose. The best way to do that would be to [URLEncode](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and encode parts of the url. Dont encode the complete URL, it wont work then. You only have to encode the parts of the url that need to be passed as values. For example in this case encode `2-0011,2-0010`

Comment: sorry. am new to android. can you explain with code please

Answer (score 0):

OK, assuming you have the URL String `mergeurl1`

```
URL url = new URL(mergeurl1);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

If you want to obtain the response ...

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
//go ahead to process your information with the inputstream
```

Finally close the HttpURLConnection by `urlConnection.disconnect();`

Please note that all the code the above cannot be run in your UI Thread, you may use a AsyncTask to cater that.

Here is the reference for you to learn about that:)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

By the way, as the comment above mentioned, you better use a `StringBuffer` to append the `String`